# How can I interrupt incoming button events in Tkinter?

Tags: python, events, tkinter, block, interrupt

My problem is if you press the "wait" button once and after that you spam the hi button when the 3 sec are over the other "hi´s" appear. Is it possible to delete the "hi" events? I want to use this for a robot and when it is moving you can spam in the same event over and over again.

```
from tkinter import *
import time

master = Tk()
fr = Frame(master, height=1500, width=500)
fr.pack()
button1 = Button(fr, text="hi", command=lambda: hi(), height=5, width=10)
button1.pack()
button2 = Button(fr, text="wait", command=lambda: wait(), height=5, width=10)
button2.pack()

def wait():
    time.sleep(3)
def hi():
    print("hi")
```